# Pine Script for Trading View: How to display on certain time frames

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

Could you kindly teach me how to not show the vertical line for timeframe of more than or equal to 1 Hour?
I desire to show the vertical lines (when the market opens) .

There is a difficulty using the iff statement alongside with the use of the likes of isIntraday and cannot compile.

Thank you in advance.

```
 //@version=2

study("Line", overlay=true)

t2 = time(period, "1800-1801")
t1 = time(period, "0300-0301")
t3 = time(period, "0930-0931")

Open2 = na(t2) ? na : blue
Open1 = na(t1) ? na : green
Open3 = na(t3) ? na : green
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show when the chart's TF is >= 60min. You can use this condition to build your display conditions:

```
//@version=2
study("")
tf60AndMore = not (isseconds or (isintraday and interval < 60))
plotchar(tf60AndMore, "tf60AndMore", "•", location.top)
```

Comment: Thank you for the share!
It seems useful, however I believe that this does not contribute to drawing a vertical line. 
I will take into consideration of your option but will continue to try to figure out a way to realize my ask!

Comment: For help on plotting a vertical line you can see [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-plot-vertical-lines-on-a-chart). And for the detection of session starts, you can see [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html).